# Is there a limit on the maximum rate of change of the position expectation value in quantum mechanics to be no greater than the speed of light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Suppose a particle, constrained to the $x$ axis, is measured at $t_0$ to be at position eigenstate $x = 0$.

Assume for all $t \gt t_0$, some external potential acts on the particle.

Nevertheless, at $t_1 \gt t_0$, the support of its position wave function must be an interval no longer than $[-c(t_1 - t_0), c(t_1 - t_0)]$ in order to satisfy special relativity.
(Here, a position wave function $\psi$ is such that $\psi \psi^*$ is the position probability density.)

Further, suppose:
At $t_1$, the position expectation value is $-c(t_1 - t_0)\lt x_{e_1} \lt c(t_1 - t_0)$
At $t_2 \gt t_1 $ the position expectation value is $-c(t_1 - t_0) \lt x_{e_2} \lt c(t_1 - t_0)$ and $x_{e_2} \ne x_{e_1}$

Also, assume there is no position measurement, after the one at $t_0$, until sometime after $t_2$.

Can we have $|(x_{e_2} - x_{e_1}|/(t_2 - t_1) \gt c$?

I think that the answer is yes, because the rate of change of the expectation value is not the same as the rate of change of measured values of position, the latter rate of change not being able to exceed $c$.

Comment: I think the only consistent relativistic quantum mechanics is relativistic quantum field theory, which doesn’t have a position operator or position wave functions.

Comment: thinking more like the Dirac equation and if that has any implications regarding how fast a position expectation value can travel. I know that the Dirac equation is not perfect, but wondering if it implies anything about this topic.

Comment: Expectation values of position operators don't travel. Can you be more specific what you mean by that?  (What travels is an object or information, not an expectation value.)

Comment: Note that the statement you expect is much stronger: If you put a particle at position $x_0=0$ and let it evolve (with a local Hamiltonian, not just "unitary evolution"), then it the probability to find it outside of $|x|\le ct$ is zero. Thus, the expectation value of the particle's position must be in the same range.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch, thank you for your replies! Yes, to be precise, I mean that If a particle, at time t0, has position expectation value of x0, and you let it evolve with a local Hamiltonian, then at t1 its expectation value will not be outside of |x| ≤ c(t1 - t0). From above, it sounds like you agree with that. However, your stronger statement that the probability outside of |x| ≤ c(t1 - t0) equals 0 makes sense, but also implies that the position wave function cannot be a Guassian wave packet, because that is nowhere exactly 0.

Comment: @user3536736 If you prepare the *initial* state as a Gaussian wavepacket, then things are different, obviously.  But the main point in relativity is that information cannot propagate faster than the speed of light.  So if there is *any* chance that you can see that you created a particle by acting in a certain region, this must be inside the light cone of that region.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch So, to wrap this up (even if a particle has an initial position state prepared as a Gaussian wavepacket), if at time $t_0$ it has expectation value $x_0$, and evolves with a local Hamiltonian, then at $t_1$ it will have some expectation value $x_1$, such that $|x_1 - x_0| ≤ c(t_1 - t_0)$ to in accordance with the fact that information cannot propagate faster than the speed of light.  Is that an accurate statement? Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear how you want to prepare a particle in a Gaussian state without acting everywhere.  If you only act on a finite spatial region, your particle will be supported in that region.

Comment: After your edit: Why do you think the answer could be "yes"? Could you substantiate, at least a little bit?  After all, one would think that the *average* of sth. which moves at most with the speed of light can *also* just move with the speed of light (which is trivial to prove).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I think yes because even if the expectation value is changing faster than the speed of light, it is still remaining within the interval that does not allow the particle to have traveled faster than light when it is next measured. Could yo please tell me what "sth." means?

Comment: "sth." mean "something".

Comment: I *think* this may just show what a mess quantum mechanics, where the wave function is interpreted as a probability amplitude, is with respect to special relativity. Need to move to the Dirac equation, where the wave function is interpreted differently, to get a good relativistic theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the system be at time $t_1$ in a state $\psi(x)$.

Decompose this state as a superposition of position eigenstates:
$$
\psi(x,t_1) = \sum_y a_y \delta(y-x)\ .
$$
The position expectation value at time $t_1$ is thus $e_1=\sum y |a_y|^2$.

Further, any of the position eigenstates can at most evolve with the speed of light, this is, if $\delta(x-x_0)$ after time $t_2-t_1$ evolved into 
$$
\phi_{x_0}(x,t_2) = \sum_y b_{y,x_0} \delta(y-(x-x_0))\ ,
$$
we have  $\big|\sum_y y |b_{y,x_0}|^2\big|\le c|t_2-t_1|$.  Note that moreover, $\sum_y |a_y|^2 = \sum_y y |b_{y,x_0}|^2 = 1$.

We can now combine the two expressions due to linearity: At time $t_2$, we have
\begin{align}
\psi(x,t_2) &= \sum_z a_z\phi_{z}(x,t_2)\\
 & = \sum_{y,z} a_z b_{y,z} \delta(y-(x-z))\ .
\end{align}
Thus, the position expectation value is
\begin{align}
|e_2-e_1| &= 
\Big|\sum_{y,z} (y+z) |a_z|^2 |b_{y,z}|^2 -\sum_z z |a_z|^2 \Big| 
\\
&= \Big|\sum_{y,z} (y+z) |a_z|^2 |b_{y,z}|^2 -\sum_{y,z} z |a_z|^2  |b_{y,z}|^2\Big| 
\\
& = \Big|\sum_{y,z} y |a_z|^2 |b_{y,z}|^2 \Big| 
\\
& \le \sum_{z} |a_z|^2 \Big| \sum_y y |b_{y,z}|^2 \Big| 
\\
& \le \sum_{z} |a_z|^2 \ c|t_2-t_1| = c|t_2-t_1|\ . 
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, Norbert. As an aside, I just looked up and found out (once knew but forgot) d<X>/dt = <P/m>, where <A> is defined to be the expectation value of A. So, the rate of change of the expectation value of position equals the expectation value of the speed, and of course the expectation value of the speed should not exceed the speed of light. https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node189.html

Comment: We recall that the teleportation of the quantum information of a qubit, from one place to another, cannot be faster than the speed of light. The idea that position expectation values cannot change at a rate faster than the speed of light sort of  seems like another special relativity theorem on quantum information, since the values of the states of a wave function are quantum information and the particular state that is the expectation value cannot change at a rate that is faster than the speed of light.